# Different payment and shipping cycles in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-subscriptions

Use case:
When a customer orders a subscription product (physical) in WooCommerce, the payment and shipping cycles are linked. Like: pay monthly, shipment is also done monthly.
I'd like to disconnect these cycles in a way that:

- payments are done monthly;
- shipment is done at start and half way of subscription period.

Example: client orders 1 year subscription for a product. Initial payment is for 1 month, but initial shipment consists of 6 products (usage for 6 months). Then, after 6 months in subscription, the last 6 products are shipped. Monthly payments continue and end at end of subscription periode (12 monthly payments in total for this example).

How can this be done?

I already investigated **Prepaid for WooCommerce Subscriptions** (https://woo.com/products/prepaid-for-woocommerce-subscriptions/), but this add-on for WooCommerce Subscriptions does exactely the opposite. Also tried **Enhancer for WooCommerce Subscriptions** that should be able to seperate the shipping cycle for subscriptions (https://woo.com/document/enhancer-for-woocommerce-subscriptions/#section-15).